# Why same function call bring different results in object internals?

Tags: perl, oop, code-generation, moose

I'm dynamically adding classes, methods and attributes using Moose::Meta::Class.

Can someone explain why this code is working (calling `generate()` subroutine internally, inside `Cat` class):

```
package Cat;

use Moose;

sub generate {

    my $siberian = Moose::Meta::Class->create( 'Siberian' );
    $siberian->add_method( echo => sub { print "yeah!\n" } );


    my $tiger = Moose::Meta::Class->create( 'Tiger' );
    $tiger->add_attribute(
        Siberian => {
            is      => 'ro',
            default => sub { $siberian->new_object; }
        },
    );

    __PACKAGE__->meta->add_attribute(
        Tiger => {
            is      => 'ro',
            default => sub { $tiger->new_object },
        },
    );

    print "Generation done!\n";
}

generate();


package main;

use Data::Printer;

my $a = Cat->new;

# $a->generate;
p( $a );
$a->Tiger->Siberian->echo;    # returns 'yeah!'
```

output of `p($a)`:

```
Cat  {
    Parents       Moose::Object
    public methods (3) : generate, meta, Tiger
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        Tiger   Tiger
    }
}
```

and this one (calling `generate` sub externally, via `$a->generate`) doesn't:

```
package Cat;
use Moose;

sub generate {

    my $siberian = Moose::Meta::Class->create('Siberian');
    $siberian->add_method(
        echo => sub { print "yeah!\n" }
    );

    my $tiger = Moose::Meta::Class->create('Tiger');
    $tiger->add_attribute(
        Siberian => {
            is      => 'ro',
            default => sub { $siberian->new_object; }
        },
    );

    __PACKAGE__->meta->add_attribute(
        Tiger => {
            is      => 'ro',
            default => sub { $tiger->new_object },
        },
    );

    print "Generation done!\n";

}

# generate();


package main;
use Data::Printer;

my $a = Cat->new;
$a->generate;
p($a);
$a->Tiger->Siberian->echo; # returns 'yeah!'
```

output of `p($a)`:

```
Cat  {
    Parents       Moose::Object
    public methods (3) : generate, meta, Tiger
    private methods (0)
    internals: {}
}
```

and program returns an error:

> Can't call method "Siberian" on an undefined value at base2.pl line
>   39.

Comment: Because when you calling $a->generate  you add this attribut to class Cat,  not to the instance of this class Cat ($a) .  And even you add to instance(object) this field  will be  not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Since `generate` is not object, but class method, it's needed to call it before `new`:

```
Cat->generate;
my $a = Cat->new;
```